# why hive can‘t select data from hdfs when use partition?

Tags: hive, hdfs, flume

I use flume to write data to hdfs,path like `/hive/logs/dt=20151002`.Then,i use hive to select data,but the count of response is always 0.

Here is my create table sql,`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id STRING)  partitioned by (dt string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/hive/logs'`

Here is my select sql,`select count(*) from test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not registering partition in hive meta-store.
Although partition is present in hdfs path,Hive won't know it if its not registered in meta store. To register it you can do the following:

> ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (dt='20151002') location '/hive/logs/dt=20151002';